# jasmine unit test for modalInstance result

Tags: jasmine

i am new to jasmine tests i could not able to find solution for this after trying in all ways i am posting it here  can any body suggest to write test case for this code which is in angular js

```
      modalInstance.result.then(function (modalOutput) {
          if (modalOutput) {
        if ('okToUndoEdits' === modalOutput[1]) {
          $scope.chargebackDetail.cbDetails = angular.copy($scope.chargebackDetailBackup.cbDetails);
        } else if ('okToSaveUnmatched' === modalOutput[1]) {
          $('#noMatchWarning').show();
          $scope.isMatchedDoc = false;
        }
      }
    }, function () {

    });
```

Comment: this is full method

Comment: iam new to jasmine can anybody help me